# registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks の引数について

Tags: java, android

Android Developersを参照すると `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` の引数は
`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` となっているのですが
実装例を見てみると `Application` クラスのインスタンスを渡しているようです。
これはキャスト？のようなことが行われているのでしょうか？
初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。

Android Developersの記述
`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback)`

[Android Developersのページ](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application?hl=ja)

実装の例

```
public class MainApplication extends Application
    implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MainApplication implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
```

ということで、その `MainApplication` は、`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` というインターフェースを継承しています。つまり、立派な `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` の一種です。

[`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application?hl=ja#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) は、`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` を引数に取るので、この `MainApplication` 自体（`this`）を渡すことが `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` を渡すことに他ならないことになります。

インターフェースなので、あくまでも、[`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` として定義された各種のメソッド](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks?hl=ja)を持つものとして扱われ、`Application` のサブクラス（`extended`）としての機能の部分は無視されます。ですから、`Application` としてのインスタンスを渡していることにはならないと思います。

つまりキャストのように、ある型から他の型へと**クラスを変換する**ようなこととは少し違うかなと。